# Android screenshot raw data conversion

Tags: android, ffmpeg, framebuffer

I'm trying to take screenshots of an Android rooted device. I managed to access the framebuffer and get the raw data. Now I have to use the ffmpeg command to convert it to a png format, like so: `ffmpeg -vcodec rawvideo -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb32 -s 240x320 -i fb0 -f image2 -vcodec png image%d.png`
My question is, where is the output png image? Where is it saved?

Answer (score 0):

It should be saved in whatever directory on your computer that you're calling the ffmpeg command from.